# How to reach a circle and detect its color?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, pixel

I have some circles located in an `image`, I could find the location for each circle (diameter and origin or centre), so first of all how could I check all pixels inside that circle (I'm thinking of for loop). second how could I ask if pixel color in nearly gray?
At first I thought of asking if Red, Green and Blue values are higher than 125 But that doesn't work. For example: (200,130,170) is for sure not a gray color!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether a point is within a circle, use pythagoras..

```
Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))
```

..to work out how far the point (x1,y1) is from the center (x2,y2) of the circle. If the value you calculate is less than the radius of the circle, the point is in the circle. This can be optimised slightly by removing the sqrt, and testing if the result is less than the square of the radius

Anything is nearly gray if the RGB are nearly the same. 64,64,64 = dark grey, 72,64,64 = slightly red looking dark grey. You'll have to define what "nearly" means

Comment: I got an answer for my 2 part, But could you be more specific regarding the 1 one, So I would accept this as an answer. my image contains around 100 of circles, so let's say that the centre point is (100,100) and the diameter is 50 pixels, how could I reach all these points with a for loop to scan them?

Comment: I need to scan only what I should do, not to scan every pixel and to ask if it's inside a circle. I could use two for loops to scan a square easily but how to use it with circle

Comment: You can do it for a square, and I’ve advised how to do it for a circle. Use the circle algorithm to test every point in the square. This is an optimisation over testing every pixel in the whole image. You could make more optimisations by not testing pixels inside the diamond whose points touch the places where the circle and square touch

Comment: As a further slight optimisation, square the radius and do away with the sqrt

Comment: I got that, Thanks